Simulating Objects with Collections in VBA
Background
I am writing a VBA module which requires the functionality of a custom object.  This object will support "regular" functions (UDFs) within the module.
Due to reasons beyond the scope of this question, standard solutions are impossible: I cannot...

...define a custom Type in my module, which has the required properties.  My module is an "optional dependency", so dependents check for its presence during execution; but Type operations fail to even compile in its absence.
...convert my module into a class for late binding, which should solve the compilation issue.  Its "regular" functions must be usable in Excel formulae; but this is impossible (I think) with methods from a class.
...use a native (Dictionary) object, which has the required functionality.  My module must be platform-agnostic; but Dictionary is unavailable on Mac.
...import a custom object into my module.  My module must be a standalone application; but this custom class adds another dependency.

Solution
It struck me that a keyed Collection resembles an object with named fields (ie. properties).  Indeed, we can mimic both fields and methods in the following way!  Here obj is an object and clx is a Collection that mimics it.



Object
Collection




obj.Field = 1
clx.Add 1, "Field"


obj.Field
clx.Item("Field")


obj.Method(...)
Method(clx, ...)



Now the native Collection solves all 4 roadblocks:

its declaration will always compile; and
it is viable in regular modules, whose functions are usable in Excel; and
it is available on Mac; and
it requires no further dependencies.

So all we need is a comprehensive API of procedures, to maintain the illusion of an object: the New_Obj() function mimics the constructor; and the Obj_*() family mimics the accessors and methods.



Functionality
Object
Mimicry API
Mimicry Description




Construction
Set x = New Obj
Set x = New_Obj()
Return a Collection populated by uninitalized values under keys.


Getting
x.Field
Obj_Field(x)
Return the value under the "Field" key.


Setting
x.Field = 1
Obj_Field x, 1
Update the value under the "Field" key.


Invocation
x.Method(...)
Obj_Method(x, ...)
A function that takes a Collection and acts like .Method().



Question
What is the best approach for the API?  I have laid out several variations below.
Code
Each of the approaches below relies on three helpers, which "extend" the Collection.  See the Helpers section for their source code.

Clx_Exists(): Test if an item exists under a given key (or at a given position).
Clx_Set(): Update the value under a given key.
Assign(): Assign any value (scalar or objective) to a variable.

Prototype
This illustration involves an "object" with a set of "fields"...

Field1 which is an Integer
Field2 which is a String
Field3 which is a Collection
...

...and a set of "methods":

Method1() which simply multiplies x by Field1
...

We implement the New_Obj() function to mimic a constructor; and the Obj_*() family of functions to mimic its accessors and methods.
' ############
' ## Fields ##
' ############

Private Const OBJ_KEY_FIELD1 As String = "Field1"
Private Const OBJ_KEY_FIELD2 As String = "Field2"
Private Const OBJ_KEY_FIELD3 As String = "Field3"
' ...



' #########
' ## API ##
' #########

' Constructor.
Public Function New_Obj( _
    Optional ByVal Field1 As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal Field2 As String, _
    Optional ByVal Field3 As Collection, _
    ' ...
) As Collection
    Dim obj As Collection: Set obj = New Collection
    
    ' Set the values for each field.
    Obj_Field1 obj, val := Field1
    Obj_Field2 obj, val := Field2
    Obj_Field3 obj, val := Field3
    ' ...
    
    ' Ensure the result is fully initialized.
    Obj_Initialize obj
    
    ' Return the result.
    Set New_Obj = obj
End Function


' Field accessors.
Public Function Obj_Field1(ByRef obj As Collection, _
    Optional ByVal val As Variant _
) As Integer
    ' Get the field value...
    Obj_Field1 = obj.Item(OBJ_KEY_FIELD1)
    
    ' ...and optionally set it.
    If Not IsMissing(val) Then
        Dim f1 As Integer: f1 = val
        Clx_Set obj, OBJ_KEY_FIELD1, f1
    End If
End Function


Public Function Obj_Field2(ByRef obj As Collection, _
    Optional ByVal val As Variant _
) As String
    ' Get the field value...
    Obj_Field2 = obj.Item(OBJ_KEY_FIELD2)
    
    ' ...and optionally set it.
    If Not IsMissing(val) Then
        Dim f2 As String: f2 = val
        Clx_Set obj, OBJ_KEY_FIELD2, f2
    End If
End Function


Public Function Obj_Field3(ByRef obj As Collection, _
    Optional ByVal val As Variant _
) As Collection
    ' Get the field value...
    Set Obj_Field3 = obj.Item(OBJ_KEY_FIELD3)
    
    ' ...and optionally set it.
    If Not IsMissing(val) Then
        Dim f3 As Collection: Set f3 = val
        Clx_Set obj, OBJ_KEY_FIELD3, f3
    End If
End Function


' Methods.
Public Function Obj_Method1(ByRef obj As Collection, _
    ByVal x As Integer _
) As Integer
    Dim f1 As Integer: f1 = Obj_Field1(obj)
    
    Obj_Method1 = x * f1
End Function

' ...



' #############
' ## Helpers ##
' #############

' Initializer.
Private Sub Obj_Initialize(ByRef obj As Collection)
    ' Ensure the "obj" collection is ready.
    If obj Is Nothing Then Set obj = New Collection
    
    
    ' Initialize fields that do not exist already.
    Dim f1 As Integer
    If Not Clx_Exists(obj, OBJ_KEY_FIELD1) Then Obj_Field1 obj, val := f1
    
    Dim f2 As String
    If Not Clx_Exists(obj, OBJ_KEY_FIELD2) Then Obj_Field2 obj, val := f2
    
    ' I want the "Field3" collection to exist AND be ready for action.
    Dim f3 As Collection
    If Clx_Exists(obj, OBJ_KEY_FIELD3) Then
        Set f3 = Obj_Field3(obj)
        If f3 Is Nothing Then Obj_Field3 obj, val := New Collection
    Else
        Obj_Field3 obj, val := New Collection
    End If
    
    ' ...
Sub

Keys
We have keyed the "fields" with String constants.  Thus we maintain them centrally, rather than hard-coding Strings everywhere.
' ############
' ## Fields ##
' ############

Private Const OBJ_KEY_FIELD1 As String = "Field1"
Private Const OBJ_KEY_FIELD2 As String = "Field2"
Private Const OBJ_KEY_FIELD3 As String = "Field3"
' ...

However, we could also use an enumeration, which would require translation into a key String.  In this case, Obj_Key(*) would replace every OBJ_KEY_*.
Private Enum ObjField
    Field1
    Field2
    Field3
    ' ...
End Enum

' ...

Private Function Obj_Key(ByVal fld As ObjField) As String
    Select Case fld
        Case ObjField.Field1: Obj_Key = "Field1"
        Case ObjField.Field2: Obj_Key = "Field2"
        Case ObjField.Field3: Obj_Key = "Field3"
        ' ...
    End Select
End Function

Optional Fields
Unlike actual objects or custom Types, which always have their full set of fields, a Collection may lack some elements.  As such, our "object" can treat certain "fields" as optional.
When this "object" has all its "fields", it technically mimics "subclass" of a similar "object" with missing "fields".  The advantage is that the absence of a field communicates different information than its uninitialized presence, so we gain flexibility of meaning.  The disadvantage is a slight divergence from the behavior of an actual object.
Here is an illustration of making Field2 an optional "field":
' Constructor.
Public Function New_Obj( _
    ' ...
    Optional ByVal Field2 As String = vbNullString, _
    ' ...
    ' ...
) As Collection
    ' ...
    
    ' Optionally include "Field2".
    If Field2 <> vbNullString Then Obj_Field2 obj, Field2
    
    ' ...
End Function

' ...

' Fields.
Public Function Obj_Field2(ByRef obj As Collection, _
    Optional ByVal val As Variant _
) As String
    ' Get any field value that MIGHT exist...
    If Clx_Exists(obj, OBJ_FLD_FIELD2) Then Obj_Field2 = obj(OBJ_FLD_FIELD2)
    
    ' ...
End Function

' ...

' Initializer.
Private Sub Obj_Initialize(ByRef obj As Collection)
    ' ...
    
    ' ' Skip initialization for "Field2".
    ' Dim f2 As String
    ' If Not Clx_Exists(obj, OBJ_FLD_FIELD2) Then Obj_Field2 obj, val := f2
    
    ' ...
End Sub

Extent of Helpers
For Private helpers, there are many tradeoffs between functionality, brevity, elegance, consistency, and ease of maintenance.

To protect certain "fields" from mutation, we might omit the val argument from their accessors.  But we can no longer use (say) Obj_Field1 obj, val := ... to update the value within New_Obj() and Obj_Initialize().

To independently maintain Obj_Field1(), without fear of disrupting functionality, we could replace its calls with Clx_Set obj, OBJ_FLD_FIELD1, ....  But this is inconsistent with using Obj_Field1(obj) to simply retrieve the value.

To preserve consistency, we could replace all calls like Obj_Field1(obj) with obj.Item OBJ_FLD_FIELD1.  But this makes the whole thing visually messy.

To restore visual elegance, we could implement these operations as Private procedures: Obj_HasField1() and Obj_GetField1() and Obj_SetField1().  But this requires 3 separate functions for every field, so the code expands dramatically with many implementations.

To centrally maintain the mechanisms for Obj_Has*() and Obj_Get*() and Obj_Set*(), we could have them wrap underlying helpers: Obj_Has() and Obj_Get() and Obj_Set().  But this adds 3 more functions to an expanding module.
Private Function Obj_Has(ByRef obj As Collection, ByVal fld As String) As Boolean
    Obj_Has = Clx_Exists(obj, fld)
End Function

Private Function Obj_Get(ByRef obj As Collection, ByVal fld As String) As Variant
    Assign Obj_Get, obj.Item(fld)
End Function

Private Function Obj_Set(ByRef obj As Collection, ByVal fld As String, ByRef val As Variant)
    Clx_Set obj, fld, val
End Function


For the sake of brevity, we could replace all instances of

Obj_Has*(obj) with Obj_Has(obj, OBJ_FLD_*)
Obj_Get*(obj) with Obj_Get(obj, OBJ_FLD_*)
Obj_Set* obj, ... with Obj_Set obj, OBJ_FLD_*, ...

This leaves us with only 3 helpers in total, rather than 3 for each "field": just Obj_Has() and Obj_Get() and Obj_Set().  But while Obj_Field1(obj) embeds the "field" name within the syntax, the new Obj_Get(obj, ...) imposes no structure on the "field" name, and we lose stability.

For the sake of stability, we could restrict the "field" to the ObjField enumeration.  But this requires Obj_Key(), which must be maintained in sync with the enumeration, so maintenance becomes decentralized.
Private Function Obj_Has(ByRef obj As Collection, ByVal fld As ObjField) As Boolean
    Obj_Has = Clx_Exists(obj, Obj_Key(fld))
End Function

Private Function Obj_Get(ByRef obj As Collection, ByVal fld As ObjField) As Variant
    Assign Obj_Get, obj.Item(Obj_Key(fld))
End Function

Private Function Obj_Set(ByRef obj As Collection, ByVal fld As ObjField, ByRef val As Variant)
    Clx_Set obj, Obj_Key(fld), val
End Function



Properties
Could we rewrite the "fields" as modular properties, to allow easy access?  We could obviously "protect" certain "fields" by making their Let/Set properties Private.
' Fields
Public Property Get Obj_Field1(ByRef obj As Collection) As Integer
    Obj_Field1 = obj.Item(OBJ_FLD_FIELD1)
End Property

Public Property Let Obj_Field1(ByRef obj As Collection, ByVal val As Integer)
    Clx_Set obj, OBJ_FLD_FIELD1, val
End Property

' ...

Public Property Get Obj_Field3(ByRef obj As Collection) As Collection
    Set Obj_Field3 = obj.Item(OBJ_FLD_FIELD3)
End Property

Public Property Set Obj_Field3(ByRef obj As Collection, ByRef val As Collection)
    Clx_Set obj, OBJ_FLD_FIELD3, val
End Property

My hope is that the API user can access the fields like so:
Debug.Print Obj_Field1(obj)

Obj_Field1(obj) = 2

' ...

Set Obj_Field3(obj) = New Collection


Helpers
Here is the code for the three helpers.
Private Function Clx_Exists(ByRef clx As Collection, _
    ByVal index As Variant _
) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Fail
    clx.Item index
    
    Clx_Exists = True
    Exit Function
    
Fail:
    Clx_Exists = False
End Function

Private Function Clx_Set(ByRef clx As Collection, _
    ByVal key As String, _
    ByRef val As Variant _
)
    If Clx_Exists(clx, key) Then
        clx.Remove key
    End If
    
    clx.Add val, key := key
End Function

Private Sub Assign( _
    ByRef var As Variant, _
    ByVal val As Variant _
)
    If IsObject(val) Then
        Set var = val
    Else
        var = val
    End If
End Sub


Would be good if you could give us an example of how this would be used in Excel as User Defined Functions. I understand what you're trying to achive from an API perspective but I have a hard time figuring out what the real use case would be. Thanks!

@CristianBuse  This "object" and its "methods" are not exposed to the Excel user.  But it supports other UDFs within my module, which are intended for Excel formulae.  I have edited my question to clarify.

@CristianBuse Can confirm by experimentation that the Property approach works!  Moreover, each Obj_*() field requires only one Get and one Let/Set, with no need for any underlying Obj_Set*() and Obj_Get*() implementations to support them, so this makes things more concise.  Finally, we can use this Obj_*(x) and  Obj_*(x) = 1 syntax throughout the module, which is much more elegant than Obj_Set x, ObjField.*, 1.  So that leaves only Obj_Has*() to resolve!

@CristianBuse I forgot to mention: the Property approach solves both tradeoffs (1) and (2).  We can protect any "field" from mutation, simply by using making its Let/Set a Private Property.  We can even protect it from reading, by doing the same for its Get.  But within the module, both its Get and Set remain fully accessible to internal procedures.  :)

Indeed, using Property makes more sense. I use this approach myself quite a lot. It's cleaner - less names to pollute the global namespace and indeed you can control scope by making them Private. I just read your post again. I am still struggling to understand why is your module optional. Why does the users code need to compile even if your module is missing?

@CristianBuse "Why does the users code need to compile even if your module is missing?" Please see my SO question about "optional dependencies". I provide a code snippet to the developer ("dev"), who pastes it into their own module of UDFs, to enhance functionality. These UDFs are used by an end user ("user") in Excel, and since this user need not be tech savvy, then they might be unaware of dependencies in VBA. So if my own module is missing as a dependency, then the snippet triggers a message to the user, and directs them to install my module.

Thanks @Greg I read the questions and the top 3 answers - I understand the idea now. This brings me to the next idea - if your module is a class (.cls instead of .bas) then if you have the Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True attribute, your class will have a global instance which you can use in your code without raising a compilation error. You would only need to have some runtime error handling in case the class is not imported. You can even expose custom types, declared in the class, via Friend methods.

Since calls to the global instance would be done at runtime then no need to recompile other modules after you import your class. Moreover, you can have a Factory method that returns instances of your class so that you don't have compilation issues i.e. you never use the New keyword outside your class. This will allow you to use as many instances as you need

Actually, I think this does not work - you would need to remove Option Explicit so that you don't get a Variable not defined compilation error. Darn, this would have been a good idea. Sorry for misleading

@CristianBuse  "I read the questions and the top 3 answers"  Thanks for taking a look!  In the end, only the top answer worked, which I and the answerer discovered through extensive experimentation and correspondence: File » Import File....  Hence the bounty.

@CristianBuse "This brings me to the next idea - if your module is a class..." I've been mulling this idea for some time, because my module is "messily" simulating a class. I'm trying to leave the door open for access to a certain global variable, which can be accessed by a UDF available in Excel, and this is why I've stuck with a module for so long. But even a class can have a static variable that all of its objects share in common, so we can have the cleaner solution without sacrificing the global variable. All we'd need is a separate module to expose the global variable via a public UDF.

@CristianBuse "...your class will have a global instance which you can use in your code without raising a compilation error." I was thinking of doing a late-binding: Dim x As Object: Set x = CreateObject("GregClass"). The IsSupported() function would catch any error, and report True when the "GregClass" object can be created, and False when it cannot. The snippet checks for this dependency with IsSupported(): True triggers regular functionality using the object; and False triggers default behavior, and prompts the Excel user with instructions to install "GregClass.cls".

CreateObject does a few things behind the scenes. First, it calls CLSIDFromProgIDEx using the ProgID (the string) you are passing. Then, it calls CoCreateInstance. The problem is that VBA classes do not have their ProgIDs in the registry so CreateObject simply doesn't work. You would need to have your class in a registered .dll file or ActiveX.exe to make this work.

Just a quick update - I gave up on the class approach as I could not find a way around removing Option Explicit. I had an idea earlier today but when I tested it did not work and so I deleted my comment here. I will be offline for a few weeks but when I get back I will surely revisit this thread. Cheers!

Thanks @CristianBuse!  I've briefly considered a .dll (or ActiveX.exe?), but I don't know where to even begin.  Since my goals are framed around user experience, for the lay user in Excel, it might ultimately be easier for them to File » Import File than to import a .dll.  So I'll build my prototype as a .bas module, but I'll create a GitHub issue that proposes a paradigm shift to a .cls class.  I'll invite you to the repo, once my version 0.1.0 is ready!

@CristianBuse  Quick correction!  I absent-mindedly wrote File » Import File, but this is incorrect.  The only viable approach is Insert » Module and then immediately Insert » File...

@CristianBuse "I gave up on the class approach as I could not find a way around removing Option Explicit.".  I just ran into the same issue with my regular module!  I need to qualify methods like GregModule.Verify() so that IsSupported() even compiles when calling Verify().  Yet once I include GregModule, then Option Explicit fails to compile with Variable not defined, because the GregModule module is not yet present.  :/  Maybe just tell the dev to deactivate Option Explicit if they want the benefits of GregModule...in which case we might as well implement a class.

"you would need to remove Option Explicit" Indeed, I often avoid using Option Explicit for this specific reason. I quite often use if isObject(stdError) then ... else .... The only other option in my mind is to scan the VBAProject typelib to see if the class exists by name. Greedo has an example of this for vbInvoke

@Sancarn  Thank you for your insight on this!  I don't much care for Option Explicit, outside of debugging, but I didn't want to abandon best practice(s) unless I must.  I'll look into these other ways of checking for dependencies: IsObject(GregModule) seems quite elegant.  While scanning the VBAProject is likely more reliable, I believe the user must enable certain trust settings in Excel, so they're probably better off importing a .dll, where CreateObject() is the cleaner code.

@Greg If you're using VBE library, yes you need to enable usage. However if you're using the type library you can do this directly in VBA with no settings applied (although without libraries it would likely be quite involved). stdCOM has partial implementation for this, and may give you some idea as to how you might do it. Otherwise vbInvoke above shows it very well. Depends how confident you are in low level though. A XLL is certainly the easiest way. A dll will require registration with regsvr so not sure how good that'd be.

An alternative could be having GregModule as an addin. I.E. GregModule.xlam. You can very easily check if an addin is loaded, so this might be the best bet among all of them. Though you wouldn't be able to get intellisense without early binding so maybe not.
